# "CRITICAL Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string" using templates with twig

Tags: fatal-error, wp-error

I'm getting the fatal error "*Critical Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string*".

The theme is developed with twig and php files, to separate logic from visual.
Somehow, in the frontend, there's no error, but I receive everyday this fatal error in the logs.

The error is in **single-color.php**:

```
$term = wp_get_post_terms( $colection->posts[0]->ID ,'look' ); 

echo'<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem"><a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Go to '.$term[0]->name.'"href="'.get_term_link( $term[0]->term_id).'" class="home"><span property="name">'.$term[0]->name.'</span></a><meta property="position" content="3"></span> > ';
```

Is there anyway to deal with this situation, just to avoid the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) returns a [`WP_Error`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) on failure. (Are you *sure* it's `$colection` and not `$collection` in that function call?)

You can check the return value using [`is_wp_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_wp_error/) and decide what you're going to output if it is, in fact, a `WP_Error`.

For example:

```
$term = wp_get_post_terms( $colection->posts[0]->ID ,'look' ); 

if ( is_wp_error( $term ) ) {

    echo 'Error: ' . $term->get_error_message();

} else {

    echo '<span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
          <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Go to ' .
          $term[0]->name . '"href="' . 
          get_term_link( $term[0]->term_id).'" class="home">
          <span property="name">'.$term[0]->name.'</span>
          </a>
          <meta property="position" content="3"></span> > ';
    // Lines broken up for readability

}
```

Comment: I know colection should have two "l" but the variable was defined as "colection". Anyway, your suggestion worked. The fatal error doesn't exist anymore. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. (I only asked about `$colection` because I know sometimes it's hard to find the typos in your own code.)